# How do I find which code is unused once my unit tests have been written?

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea

I'm developing unit tests to cover all of my code, but in IntelliJ IDEA the code no longer shows as "unused" because I have a unit tests which cover them. Is there a way to exclude unit tests from this rule? Or is there another way to identify code that isn't used?

The only solution I've thought of is to remove my entire testing folder from my project every time I want to identify these. But I would rather the ide identify unused code like it does when not unit testing. (Also, I don't need to know if the unit tests cover my code because there is already a nice feature in IntelliJ that highlights this when you run testing.)

Using IntelliJ 13.1

Comment: This is a known issue and, as far as I can see, apparently unsolved: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-56519

Comment: Is it possible to move the tests to a separate project? Ideally unit tests would only be testing public methods, but even if you need to test something that's `protected` nothing stops you from placing the tests in the same package even if they're in a separate project.

Comment: I think a separate project would force me to manually create or move the unit test classes (instead of using the very handy create test feature in IntelliJ) which would really be against my preference.